# NestJS: Class constructor Item cannot be invoked without 'new' with MariaDB 10.4.27-MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

I am working an api service with NestJS. I previously use join with MySQL version 8+ and was working just fine. However, due to specification request I have to change from MySQL to MariaDB version 10.4.27. All of the schema were migrated completely. However when I use join on typeorm it return error as "Class constructor Item cannot be invoked without 'new'". This seems to only happen when using the MariaDB database as one of the join table db.

```
  async getCashItems(type): Promise<CashItem[]> {
    return await this.cashItemRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('cashItem')
      .where('cashItem.type = :type', { type: type })
      .innerJoinAndMapOne('cashItem.item', Item, 'item', 'cashItem.item = item.id')
      .getMany();
  }
```

```
TypeError: Class constructor Item cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at SelectQueryBuilder.join (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\src\query-builder\SelectQueryBuilder.ts:2069:21)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.innerJoinAndMapOne (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\src\query-builder\SelectQueryBuilder.ts:789:14)
    at CashService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\src\cash\cash.service.ts:60:8)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:118:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:16)
    at CashService.getCashItems (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\dist\cash\cash.service.js:27:24)
    at CashController.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\api\src\cash\cash.controller.ts:37:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

```
import { ItemRarityEnum, ItemTypeEnum } from 'src/common/enums/item.enum';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('items')
export class Item {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  label: string;

  @Column()
  weight: string;

  @Column()
  rare: ItemRarityEnum;

  @Column({ name: 'can_remove' })
  canRemove: boolean;

  @Column()
  detail: string;

  @Column()
  type: ItemTypeEnum;
}
```

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mariadb',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'db',
      entities: [Item],
    }),
```

PS: setting target to 'es6', 'ES2017', 'ES2021' in tsconfig.json doesn't work

Could someone tell me what's wrong or how to set the MariaDB connection correctly?